# Precision Function Numeric Variable Error in R

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, precision, prediction

I am currently working on Neural Networks and for some odd reason I am getting a random error saying that the results need to be numeric when passing them to the precision function as it can be seen below.

Code Snippet:

```
originalValues <- max.col(dataTest[,11:15])
originalValues
predictedValues <- max.col(predictedResult)
predictedValues
CrossTable(originalValues, predictedValues, prop.r = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE,
           prop.chisq = FALSE)

originalValues
predictedValues
Accuracy(originalValues, predictedValues)
Precision(originalValues, predictedValues)
Recall(originalValues, predictedValues)
```

When running this code for some reason the Accuracy function is working and the Precision and Recall functions are working strange as seen below.

Result:

```
> originalValues
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5
> predictedValues
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
> Accuracy(originalValues, predictedValues)
[1] 0.4444444
> Precision(originalValues, predictedValues)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
> Recall(originalValues, predictedValues)
[1] NA
```